# Does EASEUS Partition Master copy the MBR when it copies partitions?

Tags: partitioning, mbr

When I copy the partition to another partition using EASEUS Partition Master, does the Master Boot Record (MBR) get copied too?

I need to boot from that copied partition so need to know if the MBR comes along with the rest of it.

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't. It only does what it says : copy the partition.
I suggest that you read with attention the EASEUS article [Partitioning Basics](http://www.partition-tool.com/easeus-partition-manager/help/partitioning-basics.htm).

The [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) is not part of any partition, so booting won't tell you anything.
You need to copy the entire disk to also copy the MBR.
Some partition backup products will also save the MBR when backuping a partition.